# Can a frictionless brachistochrone provide maximum range when projecting a mass on exit?

Tags: projectile, brachistochrone-problem

A puck is released from the top of curved, frictionless track. The puck descends, then rises again at the end, such that it leaves the track and continues in free fall until hitting the ground. The ground is assumed to be a plane on the same level as the exit point from the curve.

**Question**

Does a brachistochrone such as the one shown in the diagram, produce greatest range from the exit point? If not, how can one characterise and calculate the curve that would?

**Assumptions**

1. No friction from the slope or the air
2. The x-axis shown, represents ground level for the purposes of determining maximum range.

Please ask for any necessary clarifications before answering - thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of the puck at the exit point is fixed: it can be found from energy conservation as
$$mgh = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
$$v = \sqrt{2gh}.$$
The only way we can control the exit velocity is by adjusting the slope of the track at the exit point.
It is a [well known result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile#Ideal_projectile_motion) that a launch angle of $45^\circ$ from the horizontal maximizes the projectile range, so as long as the track smoothly curves up to a $45^\circ$ angle at the exit point, the range should be maximum.

Comment: Thank you. However that does not explain how to get the maximum exit speed and best angle from a curve that descends from height h and ends at height zero.  I want to know the *curve* that will produce the maximum range. This does not necessarily end at 45 degrees. For example, if the exit speed at the end of the track is greater following the descent along a particular path, then this extra speed may compensate for the less than ideal angle. On the other hand, a track that is constrained to end at 45 degrees may not produce the greatest exit velocity. This is not a simple problem.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica, as the answer says, the curve doesn't matter.  All curves from A to B that are smooth enough to not cause drag leave the ball with the same energy at B.  Only the exit angle matters.

Comment: @BowlOfRed - this seems to say that all pucks that exit a slope starting at height h and ending at 0, whether a level slope or a brachistochrone, will exit at the same velocity. Is that what you claim?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica The exit *speed* (not velocity) is independent of the path, as required by conservation of energy. Yes, this is the claim.

Comment: The Brachistochrone is special in that the ball reaches B in the earliest possible time.  But it has the same speed at B as other curves.

Comment: @Puk - I have trouble with this. A completely flat slope that simply hits the floor will achieve zero range. There must be an upturn at the end to achieve flight. This upturn will decelerate the puck. Whatever the upturn it will produce a range of greater than zero. The flat slope can be considered to have an upturn of zero length. Why is it different?

Comment: A flat slope has a negative exit angle, so it naturally achieves zero range. An upturn will decelerate the puck, but that doesn't mean the exit speed depends on the path. A longer (or rather "taller") upturn requires a longer descent prior to it, which means higher speed prior to the puck reaching the upturn.

Comment: @Puk - So you are saying that, as long as the flat slope has an added upturn at the end at 45 degrees - no matter how small the upturn is (assuming the puck is a point mass),  the exit velocity will always be constant?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Yes, assuming the upturn is smooth enough that the puck doesn't "bounce back" because of a sharp turn, etc.

Comment: @Puk - Great. That is indeed very illuminating. Thanks.

Comment: A follow up:  In your answer you say, "The only way we can control the exit velocity is by adjusting the slope of the track at the exit point." However, in the light of your answer, there is another way. The other (and only other) factor is the initial starting height.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Sure, I assumed that was fixed since it's specified in your diagram.